# Nuxtjs Axios onRequest() not executed for asnycData request

Tags: vue.js, axios, interceptor, nuxt.js

I have configured axios plugin `onRequest` helper to set `Authorization` header on API requests like below

```
1. export default function({ $axios, redirect, app, store }) {
2. $axios.onRequest(config => {
3.   var requestURL = config.url;
4.   console.log("Making request to " + requestURL);
5.    const token = store.state.user.account.token;
6.    if (token) {
7.      config.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
8.      console.log("Added authorization header");
9.    }
10. });
```

This `onRequest` helper get invoked for `actions` in `store`.  But for `asyncData` in page component, call reaches till line 2 above but never enters the `onRequest` function.

```
import axios from "axios";

asyncData({ params }) {
console.log("params: " + params);
return axios
  .get(`http://localhost:8080/user/id/${params.id}`)
  .then(res => {
    return { userData: res.data };
  })
  .catch(e => {
    error({ statusCode: 404, message: "User not found" });
  });
}
```

As I understand all Axios requests should pass through `onRequest` helper function. Am I missing something here? How to fix this?

Comment: I am still learning how to properly work with nuxt, axios and the auth module. Where do you place the first block of code you wrote here ? is it as a middleware, or a plugin that you add as an extension to axios ?

Answer (score 2):

When you `import axios from 'axios'` you're not using the configuration for the axios instance that you specified initially. Instead, you're using an entirely new axios instance.

The correct way would be to leverage the `$axios` instance from the `Nuxt context`.

```
asyncData(context) {
   await context.$axios...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `$axios` instance directly. An example is:

```
asyncData({$axios}) {
   await $axios...
}
```