# Nuxt axios interceptors not logging as expected

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I have created an `axios.js` file as per the [documentation](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend.html) to extend axios as I want to trigger a loader every time a request is made:

```
export default function({ $axios, store }) {
  console.log(store)
  // request
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
    console.log('request')
  })

  // response
  $axios.onResponse((res) => {
    console.log('response')
  })

  // error
  $axios.onError((config) => {
    console.log('error')
  })
}
```

However nothing is being logged in the browser when a request is made.  Not sure what I am doing wrong but when I add interceptors directly to the axios object it is fine.  I am not sure how to commit an action when doing that though.

I have added the plugin like so:

```
/*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: ['@/plugins/filters.js', './plugins/axios.js'],
```

`filters` is working as expected

I am using middleware to send an action:

```
export default function({ store }) {
  return store.dispatch('getProducts')
}
```

And the action uses axios:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const actions = {
  async getProducts({ commit }) {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get(`${process.env.browserBaseUrl}`)
      commit('getProducts', result.data.quotes)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    } finally {
      console.log('We do cleanup here')
    }
  },
  setCurrentFilter({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('setCurrentFilter', payload)
  }
}

export default actions
```

Comment: Did you add the plugin in nuxt.config.js?

Comment: Can you please show how you use axios to do a request?

Comment: Logging the store outputs the store in the console as expected.  I can see my baseUrl configured in nuxt.config.js in there so looks good.

Comment: Check if you import axios from 'axios', maybe that is the error https://stackoverflow.com/a/59807291/10781526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to import if axios is already registered as plugin. You can use axios like this - `this.$axios.$get('url', ()=> {})`. Maybe that's why it is happening.

Comment: That works but i am not sure how to mock axios in my actions test?

axios.get.mockResolvedValue({ data })

no longer works

Comment: You need to add $ if front of every axios methods if you're using it as plugin. So, try changing it to this.$axios.$get.mockResolvedValue. Also, post methods would be this.$axios,$post, and so on

Comment: the keyword this would not point to the same thing though?  As in actions file this would point to the global Vue instance but in jest it points to something else?

Comment: Yes, the keyword 'this' depends on the scope of the class. So, make sure the scope doesn't change inside the function. So, the best practice would be to use arrow functions. ES6's function short hand syntax inside an object also works too.